# Python curses - textpad.Textbox() keyboard input not working with German umlauts

Tags: python, encoding, ncurses, curses, python-curses

I'm trying to use the curses `textpad.Textbox()` function for text input. Everything is working fine so far, however, some keys don't get recognized, including the section sign (§) and all German umlauts (ä/ö/ü). I guess it's somehow related to the text encoding, but I have no idea how to fix this. My German keyboard layout works perfectly fine with `input()`.

Here is some minimal example:

```
    import curses
    import curses.textpad as textpad

    try:
        stdtscr = curses.initscr()
        curses.cbreak()
        stdtscr.keypad(1)
        curses.noecho()

        textpad.Textbox(stdtscr).edit()

    finally:
        curses.nocbreak()
        stdtscr.keypad(0)
        curses.echo()
        curses.endwin()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just as in C, you should initialize the locale.  It's spelled out in both the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html):

> Since [version 5.4](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/announce-5.4.html), the ncurses library decides how to interpret non-ASCII data using the nl_langinfo function. That means that you have to call locale.setlocale() in the application and encode Unicode strings using one of the system’s available encodings.

and the [ncurses manual page](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization):

```
   The  library uses the locale which the calling program has
   initialized.  That is normally done with setlocale:

           setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

 If the locale is not initialized, the library  assumes  that
 characters are printable as in ISO-8859-1, to work with cer-
 tain legacy programs.  You should initialize the locale  and
 not  rely on specific details of the library when the locale
 has not been setup.
```

Addressing the followup comment, [textpad.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/curses/textpad.py) does not expect UTF-8 input in any case.  Essentially it "validates" its input, decides it isn't ASCII and ignores it when it's not.

Python's [curses binding](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html#curses.window.getch) provides an interface to [`wgetch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters), which (with **ncurses**) gives the individual bytes for the UTF-8.  (X/Open Curses specifies a different function [`wget_wch`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_get_wch.3x.html), for which Python has no binding).

`textpad.py` could be modified to work around the curses binding by assembling the bytes into a Unicode value, but you'd need the `setlocale` as the first step.

Comment: I already tried that but it doesn't change anything, the aforementioned keys still don't work.