# Displaying Unicode properly in curses

Tags: unicode, python-3.6, curses, python-curses

I want to draw a graphic using block characters using the Python 3.6 curses module. However, when I try to show a string like:

```
screen = curses.addstr(2,2,'▄ •▄       ▄▄▄▄·       ▄▄▌  ·▄▄▄▄      .▄▄▄  ▄• ')
```

it does not display properly and instead spits out gibberish like

```
â–„ â€¢â–„       â–„â–„â–„â–„Â·       â–„â–„â–Œ  Â·â–„â–„â–„â–„      .â–„â–„â–„  â–„â€¢ â–„â–Œâ–„â–„
```

when I try to refresh the display.

Is there any way to properly display Unicode characters using the curses module? Using the print() command displays them just fine.

Edit: I'm not trying to have the curses module receive unicode text, I'm just trying to get it to display properly. I have written

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,"")
```

before my code and it still does not work.

Comment: Assuming the underlying library is *ncursesw*, the only other thing to check for is whether Python is calling `setlocale`.  By the way, the system and package names help, when asking about how to use a given feature.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python curses - textpad.Textbox() keyboard input not working with German umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510606/python-curses-textpad-textbox-keyboard-input-not-working-with-german-umlauts)

Comment: I put the line locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL,'') in my code before calling initscr and it still does not work. What do you mean by the system and package names?

Comment: system - Arch Linux, Debian, etc.   According to the system, there's likely (unless you compiled Python yourself) a package-name and version.

Comment: I'm on Windows right now, and I'm using Python 3.6.1 / Anaconda 4.4.0 win32,

Comment: There's **Windows** and **Cygwin**, each with its own problems and limitations.  Stating that in the question is the way to start off.  The mixture of characters makes it look as if you're using UTF-8 on a device which does not support that.

Comment: Sorry, I'm a bit green when it comes to programming. I'm currently running Windows, not Cygwin, and I think my computer is able to support it - running the command print('▄ •▄       ▄▄▄▄·       ▄▄▌  ·▄▄▄▄      .▄▄▄  ▄• ') displays the text in the command line perfectly.